# npm update/npm install returns dependency error after installing @angular/localize

Tags: angular, npm, nestjs, nrwl-nx, angular-localize

I want to use @angular/localize for my angular application. I am using a recently created nestjs backend with an Angular frontend in a Nx monorepo.

When trying to add the Package with `npm install @angular/localize` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @wordle-ase/source@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@17.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~17.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"17.2.3" from @angular/localize@17.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   @angular/localize@"^17.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

As I want a clean package installation with no dependency issues I do not want to use `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`.

When I saw @angular/localize@17.2.3 depends on @angular/compiler@17.2.3 and I only had version 17.1.3 installed, I tried installing version 17.1.3 of localize as well (`npm install @angular/localize@17.1.0`). This command returned no errors.

If I use the command `npm update` and  also `npm install` afterwards though, I get a very similar error message:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @wordle-ase/source@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@17.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~17.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"17.2.3" from @angular/localize@17.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   @angular/localize@"^17.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Why do I get this error? Is it fixable or is it even intended behavior?
Can I not update my other packages if there is an issue with @angular/localize? Why can I not reinstall all packages without an error even though there was no dependency issue when first installing it?

In case it is useful, here is my full package.json-File:

```
{
  "name": "@wordle-ase/source",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {},
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "~17.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~17.1.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.2.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^10.0.4",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.2",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.3.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "^18.0.5",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.2.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~17.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~17.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~17.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.2.1",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.2",
    "@nx/eslint": "18.0.3",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "18.0.3",
    "@nx/jest": "18.0.5",
    "@nx/js": "18.0.5",
    "@nx/nest": "^18.0.3",
    "@nx/node": "18.0.3",
    "@nx/web": "18.0.3",
    "@nx/webpack": "18.0.3",
    "@nx/workspace": "18.0.3",
    "@schematics/angular": "~17.1.0",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.8.0",
    "@swc/core": "~1.3.85",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "~18.16.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.13.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.13.2",
    "eslint": "~8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.13.4",
    "jest": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-environment-node": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "~13.1.4",
    "jsonc-eslint-parser": "^2.1.0",
    "nx": "18.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is intended behaviour. Your `package.json` says `"@angular/compiler": "~17.1.0"` should be installed, which is **not** compatible with the peer requirement from `@angular/localize` (where `^17.1.3` **also allows 17.2**). At least for the `@angular` dependencies, you need to be internally consistent, in your case make them all `~` not `^`. https://semver.npmjs.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try changing that. Is there a reason why npm doesn’t do ~ an ^ in the correct way automatically?

Comment: It's using the default [`save-prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/config#save-prefix), `^`; if you want something different you need to change that configuration, either globally, at project level or for the specific command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change next two fields in your package.json

```
"@angular/compiler": "~17.1.0",
"@angular/localize": "^17.1.3",
```

to

```
"@angular/compiler": "^17.1.0",
"@angular/localize": "^17.1.0",
```

and run `npm install`.